# Where does the turtle (and its screen) appear in scipy/anaconda/spyder (2.7)?

Tags: python, scipy, turtle-graphics, spyder

I'm using SciPy/Anaconda/Spyder and when I put in:

```
import turtle
from turtle import Turtle
turtle.getscreen()
turtle.showturtle
```

and run it nothing happens. Whereas in IDLE when the script is run a new screen appears with a "turtle" (the turtle being a right pointing arrow head) in the middle of it.

Where does the "turtle screen appear" in SciPy/Anaconda/Spyder?

Comment: Thanks for the layout fix. How did you put the code in the gray section?

Comment: Code blocks are indented by four whitespaces. Click on 'edit' to see the source, you can also use the editor yourself (next time).

Answer (score 2):

To make this work you need to:

1. Select the *IPython* Console instead of the Python one
2. Enter this command there: `%gui tk`
3. Run your provided code (it works for me on Linux).

*Note*: If you are on Windows, unfortunately there is a bug in Anaconda that prevents people to use the `turtle` module. This bug is not related to the module itself but to the graphical toolkit it uses to create the turtle animations.